# recommended procedure for loading older svn dump and then updating files

Tags: svn, dump, subclipse

Here is the situation:

My most recent backup of the svn dump file is for (say) revision 7150. However, the most recent version of the files on my SVN client (subclipse on windows eclipse) is 7175.  At this point the server filesystem crashed in a non-recoverable way.  So, I do not have the latest dump.

To go about creating a new repository on a new server (centos linux), I can load the repository and it will be current till 7150.  Should I create a new folder on my client and checkout the repo to this location (i.e., will the old repo on the client will be obsolete as it points to the old instance?).  Also, given that I will be missing the file changes from 7150 to 7175, what is a recommended way to sync the new repo to the latest state (7175)?  Perhaps if I manually copy the changed files, then a single commit can update to 7151 (similar state as 7175 on the old system)?  Thanks in advance for any pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your current client was checked out to revision 7175 -- a revision that no longer exists.

Do a new checkout, and copy over the files in your current working directory (rev 7175) over to the new checked out working directory (rev 7150). If you're using a Subversion 1.7 client, the only `.svn` directory will be in the root of the checkout, so it's pretty easy to copy everything over (just don't overwrite that new `.svn` directory!). If you're using a pre-version 1.7 client, watch out for the `.svn` directories in all of your directories in your tree.

Your new revision will be revision 7151 and not 7175 or 7176. The old change history between the old revision 7151 and 7174 will be gone. No more. You no longer know who changed them or why.

Comment: Thanks. My original suspicions were on the right track (new checkout etc.).  I am using an older svn client that creates .svn in all the folders and so I will just copy over the modified files since 7150.